# Proof that $\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(Ct)^p (\sqrt{p})^p}{p!} \leq Ae^{Bt^2}$ for some constants $A, B > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Fix $C > 0.$ I need to prove that there are constants $A, B> 0$ (depending on $C$) such that

$$\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(Ct)^p (\sqrt{p})^p}{p!} \leq Ae^{Bt^2}$$

for every $t>0.$

Sorry for not showing any work, but I don't really know how to tackle this. Thanks.

Comment: Write out the $e^{Bt^2}$ as a power series. At first glance I think your statement is only true for $t > 1$ and false for $0 < t <=1$

Comment: If $C$ and $t$ are fixed can't you always choose $A=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(Ct)^p (\sqrt{p})^p}{p!}$ and $B=t^{-2}$?

Comment: No. I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(t)$ denote the sum. Then for $t > 0$,

\begin{align*}
f'(t)
&= \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{C^p p^{p/2}}{(p-1)!} t^{p-1} \\
&= C + \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{C^{p+2} (p+2)^{(p+2)/2}}{(p+1)!} t^{p+1} \\
&= C + C^2 t \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{C^{p} p^{p/2}}{p!} \left( \frac{(p+2)^{(p+2)/2}}{p^{p/2}(p+1)} \right) t^{p}.
\end{align*}

Since

$$ \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{(p+2)^{(p+2)/2}}{p^{p/2}(p+1)} = e $$

is finite, it follows that $M = \sup_{p \geq 0} \frac{(p+2)^{(p+2)/2}}{p^{p/2}(p+1)}$ is also finite. From this, we get

$$ f'(t) \leq C + C^2 M t f(t) $$

Writing $B = C^2M/2$ and using the above bound, it follows that

$$ (e^{-Bt^2}f(t))' = e^{-Bt^2}(f'(t) - 2Btf(t)) \leq Ce^{-Bt^2}, $$

and so,

$$ e^{-Bt^2}f(t) - f(0)
\leq \int_{0}^{t} C e^{-Bs^2} \, \mathrm{d}s
\leq \int_{0}^{\infty} C e^{-Bs^2} \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

Setting $A = f(0) + \int_{0}^{\infty} C e^{-Bs^2} \, \mathrm{d}s$, we therefore obtain

$$ f(t) \leq A e^{Bt^2}  $$

as desired.

Comment: In fact, computing $A$, we have the stronger result that it is independent of $C$. Indeed,  evaluating the integral yields that $A=1+\sqrt{\pi/2M}$.